# create custom carousel with 3 items jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

i wanna create a carousel with 3 item like this picture

[image]

by click on left arrow b2 is most left , b3 is center and  b1 is right most and vice versa for right arrow. ans also by click on each item it must come to center.
i created something but that isn't carousel! my way was by inserting one item before or after another.

```
$('div #item2').after($('div #item1'));
```

and i must note that i review some plugins like slick,.. but i wanna its be custom coded by myself.
thank

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly: you DONT want a plugin to solve this?

Comment: _"but i wanna its be custom coded by myself"_ yet you are asking others to do it for you?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) carouselJquary plugin

```
<div data-slick='{"slidesToShow": 4, "slidesToScroll": 4}'>
  <div><h3>1</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2</h3></div>
  <div><h3>3</h3></div>
  <div><h3>4</h3></div>
  <div><h3>5</h3></div>
  <div><h3>6</h3></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(element).slick()
```